# confusion with priority queue in java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have some array indices which i want to put into priority queue. Now I want to use a comparator which should compare this indices with respect to another array in same class. How should I write the comparator class?

Comment: Show something that you have tried so far?

Comment: *compare this indices with respect to another array in same class* I don't make any sense out of this statement. What are you looking to compare? And what are you adding to your priority queue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your actual question, if you have those indices mapped to whatever `Comparable` values (within that "external" array) and you want to set the priority based on that value, you can simply go with:

```
Comparable[] array = TheOtherClass.getArray(); // ???
Comparator<Integer> comparator = (left, right) -> array[left].compareTo(array[right]);
```